# User is always none, doesn't allow the user to sign in

Tags: django, django-authentication

While creating a login and signup form, I have been having issues with the sign up form, the issue is that whenever I create user through registration and try to log in with the test user it doesn't log, always points the Httpresponse I have set up. After checking the admin panel the user is being created, now I do not know where to go, I do think I am not grabbing the right data or its not grabbing it

```py
## Register
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'auth/register.html', { })
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = form.cleaned_data['password']
            passwordConf = form.cleaned_data['passwordConf']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']

            user = User.objects.create_user(username, password, email)

            if password == passwordConf:
                return HttpResponseRedirect("/auth/signin")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Passwords do not match", status=400)   
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Invalid registration request.(Bad Request)", status=400)

    else:
        form = RegistrationForm      
        return HttpResponse("Method not allowed on /auth/register.(Method Not Allowed)", status=405)


## Signin
def signin(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render(request, 'auth/signin.html', { })

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SigninForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            username = request.POST["username"]
            password = request.POST["password"]
            user = authenticate(request, username=username, password=password)
            if user is not None:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid Credientials', status=401 )
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Form is not valid", status=401)
```

Comment: Which HttpResponse is it going to?I see two response in signin view

Comment: It always hits invalid credientials

Comment: try printing `username` and `password` fields, do they return the correct values entered by you?

Comment: Yes they print the correct values, I was starting to think maybe something is wrong when the user is being created

Comment: maybe that is the case, try creating a new user in the django admin and use that credentials to test this

Comment: Is this line `user = User.objects.create_user(username, password, email)` creating the user. I doubt. One more thing, you should save user after passowrd = passwordconf not before.

Comment: rather even create the user after `if password == passwordConf:`

Comment: Creating a user on the django admind, I still the get the error, it seems like it is when the user is either being created or something is up with the  signin form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `create_user` is sending a different order of arguments than expected. According to [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user), it has the signature `create_user(username, email=None, password=None, **extra_fields)`.

Currently, by using `user = User.objects.create_user(username, password, email)`, you are setting `user.email=password` and `user.password=email`.

You need to use:

```
user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
```

Answer (score 0):

may be your user is inactive, i.e. `is_active` is `False`. You either need

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ['django.contrib.auth.backends.AllowAllUsersModelBackend']
```

in your settings or set `is_active` to `True`.

**Docs**: [Default backend](https://github.com/django/django/blob/571ab44e8a8936014c22e7eebe4948d9611fd7ce/django/contrib/auth/backends.py#L29-L35) is checking for `is_active` first, thats the reason.

Comment: doesn't the `User.objects.create_user` already set the `is_active` to True by default?